# how to delete all files using wget method delete in bash

Tags: bash, wget

I can remove an individual file with`method=DELETE` in `wget`, but what if there are 100 files to delete, how can all off them be removed?  I tried `*` but wildcards are not supported.  Thank you :).

```
wget --user=xxx --password=xxx --xxx --method=DELETE \
xxxx://www.xxxx.com/xxx/xx/xxxx/myfile.foo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if this operation has been implemented on the domain you are trying to perform that command. Consult the (REST ?) API of the service, it might be documented on the website.

FYI from [Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.7) :

> The DELETE method requests that the origin server delete the resource
>   identified by the Request-URI. This method MAY be overridden by human
>   intervention (or other means) on the origin server. The client cannot
>   be guaranteed that the operation has been carried out, even if the
>   status code returned from the origin server indicates that the action
>   has been completed successfully. However, the server SHOULD NOT
>   indicate success unless, at the time the response is given, it intends
>   to delete the resource or move it to an inaccessible location.